# How to sum the two numbers after a .getJSON request using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I've used `.getJSON` function to get shares and counts for a specific URL and I successfully got the shares and counts but I want the sum of these two too. This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wm9M3/1028/) I made.

This is the Jquery I used

```
$(function () {
  var fburl = "http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html";

  $.getJSON(fburl, function (data) {

     var fbshares = data["shares"];
     $(".facebook").append(fbshares);
  });

  twitterurl = 'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html&callback=?';

  $.getJSON(twitterurl, function (data) {
     var twittershares = data["count"];
     $(".twitter").append(twittershares);
  });

  var sumofboth = fbshares + twittershares;

  $(".sum").append(sumofboth);
```

});

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: most likely `fbshares` and `twittershares` are being passed as a `string`... did you try with `parseInt(fbshares, 10) + parseInt(twittershares, 10)` ? And please add `var fbshares = 0, twittershares = 0` to the start of your code!

Comment: Your variables are local scoped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the `async=true` of `getJSON`
You have to make everything inside the first `getJSON`.
Or use ajax without async

http://jsfiddle.net/v8gw6/1/

Comment: You don't *have* to do everything inside the first request handler. This works, but you get the response quicker if one doesn't have to wait for the other.

Comment: Guffa you are right but it is better for wait for first and then load second because in the end if both are not loaded then sum will be not achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You have specified `fbshares` and `twittershares` inside the `$.getJSON` and trying to access it outside the functions. So the variables are not available.

Declare them at the top and try to access it.

Meanwhile both are async requests, so they may resolve at two different times.

To overcome that you can use `$.promise , $.when or $.deferred.`

Here is an example with `$.when`

```
 $(function(){

     var fbshares, twittershares, sumofboth;

     $.when($.getJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html", function (data) {
         fbshares = data["shares"] || 0; // assign 0 if it returns undefined
         (".facebook").append(fbshares);
     }), $.getJSON("http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html&callback=?", function (data) {
        twittershares = data["count"] || 0;  // assign 0 if it returns undefined
        $(".twitter").append(twittershares);
     }).done(function(){
       sumofboth = fbshares + twittershares;
       $(".sum").append(sumofboth);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not enough. As the requests are asynchronous, the values haven't been set yet when you try to use them.

Comment: Ya.. didn't notice. I have updated the answer. Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason the above example does not work is that you are making each request asynchronously. That is, you are reaching the code that is summarizing your results before the results have been retrieved.

If you instead make each query in turn and sum the results after all queries are complete it works much better.

Check this out.
http://jsfiddle.net/Wm9M3/1037/

```
$(function () {

    var fburl = "http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html";

    var twitterurl = 'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html&callback=?';

    // first make your request for the facebook info
    $.getJSON(fburl, function (data) {
        var fbshares = data["shares"];
        $(".facebook").append(fbshares);

        // once the FB info is complete get the twitter info
        $.getJSON(twitterurl, function (data) {
            var twittershares = data["count"];
            $(".twitter").append(twittershares);

            // once we are here both FB and Twitter info has been retrieved
            // lets summarize them
            var sumofboth = fbshares + twittershares;
            $(".sum").append(sumofboth);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As the requests are asynchronous, you have to wait until both responses have arrived before you can calculate the sum. Declare the variables outside the success handlers so that each can check if the other has arrived, and let the last one to arrive show the sum:

```
$(function () {
  var fbshares = null;
  var twittershares = null;

  function showSum() {
    var sumofboth = fbshares + twittershares;
    $(".sum").append(sumofboth);
  }

  var fburl = "http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html";

  $.getJSON(fburl, function (data) {
     fbshares = data["shares"];
     $(".facebook").append(fbshares);
     if (twittershares != null) showSum();
  });

  twitterurl = 'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html&callback=?';

  $.getJSON(twitterurl, function (data) {
     twittershares = data["count"];
     $(".twitter").append(twittershares);
     if (fbshares != null) showSum();
  });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6NXYg/

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the vars *`fbshares, twittershares`* outside of your functions:

```
$(function () {
  var fburl = "http://graph.facebook.co........multi.html",
      twitterurl = 'http://urls.api.twitter.com/.....html&callback=?',
      fbshares, 
      twittershares,
      sumofboth; // declare it here to access

  $.getJSON(fburl, function (data) {
     fbshares = data["shares"] || 0; // update the var value here
     $(".facebook").append(fbshares);
  }).promise().done(function(){ // use promise to wait for values to get set
     sumofboth = fbshares + twittershares;
     $(".sum").append(sumofboth);
  });
  $.getJSON(twitterurl, function (data) {
     twittershares = data["count"] || 0;  // update the var value here
     $(".twitter").append(twittershares);
  }).promise().done(function(){ // use promise to wait for values to get set
     sumofboth = fbshares + twittershares;
     $(".sum").append(sumofboth);
  });
});
```

---

As **Guffa** suggested that values are not getting set as there are two calls are asynchronous so it will take time to set the values so you have to use a `.promise()` to get it completed and in the done function we will add the values and set them.

---

Another solution is to use it with `jQuery.when()` method this way:

```
$(function () {
  var fburl = "http://graph.facebook.co........multi.html",
      twitterurl = 'http://urls.api.twitter.com/.....html&callback=?',
      fbshares, 
      twittershares,
      sumofboth; // declare it here to access

  $.when($.getJSON(fburl, function (data) {
     fbshares = data["shares"] || 0; // update the var value here
     $(".facebook").append(fbshares);
  }), $.getJSON(twitterurl, function (data) {
     twittershares = data["count"] || 0;  // update the var value here
     $(".twitter").append(twittershares);
  }).done(function(){
     sumofboth = fbshares + twittershares;
     $(".sum").append(sumofboth);
  });
});
```

---

[jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

**Description:**
Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

Comment: That's not enough. As the requests are asynchronous, the values haven't been set yet when you try to use them.

Comment: @Guffa Hmmm....yes you are correct, i think then there `promise().done()` has to be used.

Comment: Then to wait for both values you would need to use one promise from each request.

Answer (score 0):

Your scope of the variable is not visible out side and also after the request get You have to use that varible

```
    $(function () {
        var fburl = "http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html";
        var checker = 0;
        var fbshares, twittershares;
        $.getJSON(fburl, function (data) {

            fbshares = data["shares"];
            $(".facebook").append(fbshares);

            checker += 1;
        });
        twitterurl = 'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html&callback=?';
        $.getJSON(twitterurl, function (data) {

            twittershares = data["count"];
            $(".twitter").append(twittershares);


            checker += 1;
        });

        var cache = setInterval(function () {
            if (checker == 2) {
                var sumofboth = fbshares + twittershares;
                $(".sum").append(sumofboth);
                clearInterval(cache);
            }
        }, 100);

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wm9M3/1033/)

[NEW Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wm9M3/1038/)

Comment: Doesn't work when the twitter response arrives first.

Comment: Yes, that works, but I don't think that using an interval is a god way to wait for something to happen when you already have event handlers for when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You've a couple of problems.
1) variables scope
2) neglecting asynchronous nature of ajax calls

Following code will work for you

```
    $(function () {
        //twittershares and fbshares variables made global
        var fburl = "http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html",
           twitterurl,
           fbshares = -1,
           twittershares,
           sumofboth,
           interval;

        $.getJSON(fburl, function (data) {
           fbshares = data["shares"];
           $(".facebook").append(fbshares);
        });

        twitterurl = 'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html&callback=?';
        $.getJSON(twitterurl, function (data) {
           twittershares = data["count"];
           $(".twitter").append(twittershares);

           //fb ajax request isn't guaranteed to have returned response so check for fb response every 250 milliseconds and update div
           interval = window.setInterval(function () {
              if (fbshares != -1) {
                 sumofboth = parseInt(fbshares, 10) + parseInt(twittershares, 10);
                 $(".sum").append(sumofboth);
                 window.clearInterval(interval);
              }
           }, 250);
        });
     });
```

Comment: If the facebook request takes 2 seconds, and twitter returns result after 1 second, then this would not work would it?

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON internally uses jQuery ajax. so make sure both variables have values before sum up. Instead use jquery ajax with async:false

```
$(function () {
      var fburl = "http://graph.facebook.co........multi.html",
          twitterurl = 'http://urls.api.twitter.com/.....html&callback=?',
          fbshares=0, 
          twittershares=0; // declare it here to access



        $.ajax({url:fburl,async:false, function (data) {
             fbshares = data["shares"]; // update the var value here
             $(".facebook").append(fbshares);
add(fbShares,twittershares);
          }});
          $.ajax({url:twitterurl,async:false, function (data) {
             twittershares = data["count"];  // update the var value here
             $(".twitter").append(twittershares);
add(fbShares,twittershares);
          }});


        });
function add(a,b)
{
$(".sum").append(a+b);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using synchronous requests. The browser will freeze completely while it is waiting for the responses.

Comment: then declare fbShares,twittershares with 0 and call add method in ajax success callback event

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code, put variables outside the ajax call and parse Result to float like this:

```
   $(function(){
var fburl = "http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html";
    var fbshares;
    var twittershares;
$.getJSON(fburl, function(data){

     fbshares = parseFloat(data["shares"]);
    $(".facebook").append(fbshares);
});
twitterurl='http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html&callback=?';
$.getJSON(twitterurl, function(data){

      twittershares = parseFloat(data["count"]);
 $(".twitter").append(twittershares);
    var sumofboth=fbshares+twittershares;
    $(".sum").append(sumofboth);
});

});
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RkWZR/)